# Caesar cipher that shifts each letter by a different value?

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

The goal is to have a program that I can input, for example, "helloworld" and "0123456789", and receive "hfnosbuytm" as the output. Unlike a regular Caesar cipher, it's only meant to shift by between 0 and 9 letters per character. Both the string and the key are the same length, so I understand that I need to use the same length value and shift them in a for loop, but I'm having trouble with the syntax. Here's what I ended up with:

```
def getdigit(number, n):
    return int(number) // 10**n % 10

message = "helloworld"
key = "0123456789"
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
encoded = "".join([alphabet[(alphabet.find(char)+getdigit(key, char))%26] for char in message])
print(encoded)
```

But it gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ants\mu_code\blank.py", line 7, in <module>
    encoded = "".join([alphabet[(alphabet.find(char)+getdigit(key, char))%26] for char in message])
  File "c:\users\ants\mu_code\blank.py", line 7, in <listcomp>
    encoded = "".join([alphabet[(alphabet.find(char)+getdigit(key, char))%26] for char in message])
  File "c:\users\ants\mu_code\blank.py", line 2, in getdigit
    return int(number) // 10**n % 10
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'str'
```

which I don't understand at all. I've gotten various other syntax errors when trying to rearrange the code, as well.

Comment: _TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'str'_ That's an easy one, I'm sure you can do this! It says the error is related to the types of the values in the `**`: Those two values are `10` and `n`, I'll let you guess which one is problematic ;)

Comment: This is known as a [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad) cipher, except you limited yourself to only shifting each letter by up to 9.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a type error, because you defined the `getdigit` function as taking `number` as a string and `n` as an integer, but then you called this function like `getdigit(key, char)` where `key` is a string and `char` is also a string - it's a single letter from `message`, since it comes from `for char in message`.

To directly fix this won't be trivial, because `n` ought to be the *index* where `char` occurs in `message`, but your code doesn't know the index, and you can't use the `message.index(char)` method to find it because this gives the index of the *first* occurrence of `char`, not the index of the *current* occurrence. The [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function can be used to access the indices in your list comprehension.

That said, it would be much simpler to write your code in such a way that you don't need the indices. You could simplify your code by using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up letters from `message` with the corresponding digits from `key`. This looks like a homework task, so I won't show a full solution, but the following might give you an idea about how to do it:

```py
>>> message = "helloworld"
>>> key = "0123456789"
>>> for char, digit in zip(message, key):
...     print('char:', char, 'digit:', digit)
... 
char: h digit: 0
char: e digit: 1
char: l digit: 2
char: l digit: 3
char: o digit: 4
char: w digit: 5
char: o digit: 6
char: r digit: 7
char: l digit: 8
char: d digit: 9
```